# Is any way in fluent NH to map Views?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is any way in fluent NH to map [View]s to c# classes? I need to have them read-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NHibernate allows you to map views as you would a table. It's exactly the same. The only thing you can't do is update it.

Comment: SQL Server allows insert and updates to views if certain conditions are met. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate does not know if the object you specify as "table" is actually a table or a view.

If you're not going to write to them, there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the other answers you can map a view exactly the same way as a table. I would configure them read-only in order to have non-allowed inserts caught in your application and not returned as error from the database:

```
public class MyViewMapping : ClassMap<MyViewType>
{
    public MyViewMapping()
    {
        Table("VIEW_NAME");

        ReadOnly();

        // Add all view fields here...
        Map(x => x.Field1, "Field1Name");
    }
}
```